# Why does my iPhone disconnect from wireless when it is in use?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

Whenever I watch videos through the YouTube app on my iPhone 4 (iOS 6.1.3), after being on wireless for a while it will often spontaneously disconnect and start downloading from the 3G network. I only have a 200 MB data plan so this is a major problem. I'm guessing it is not app-specific, I just only happen to notice it with YouTube. I have 3/3 bars of wireless signal and my laptop in the same location has no problem so I don't think it's an issue with the wireless. I've tried restoring various levels of default settings and the entire phone to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could comment, but do not have enough reputation.  Since it sounds like this problem is isolated solely to your specific iPhone, it sounds like it could be a problem with your router, or maybe the antenna in the phone itself is some how damaged.  I know you said you don't think it could be a problem with your wireless router, but do you experience any of the same problems when using any other devices?  My recommendation would be to reset your router to factory settings and then using your iPhone to view or download a large file over that connection.

I really do think it is a problem with your router, as I have seen other wireless connections exhibit the same problems when they are about to fail.

Comment: I don't think it's phone hardware or router because if I turn off cellular data it has no problem staying on wifi.

Comment: Interesting, since you've restored the phone, there must be a hardware failure, or some other problem with the phone.  I would take up this issue with apple and see what they have to say.  Seems like you have ruled out everything but the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://alvinalexander.com/apple/iphone-ios-using-cellular-data-home-wifi-network/:

Try disable IPhone using Cellular Data when there is WiFi

[image: WiFi Assist]

Then you can check how good your router actually is and fix if needed.

When there is using 2 connections, it maybe temp delay that would make the switch, but only to make things worse.

---

Similar if you have 2 SIM cards (or SIM + eSIM), you may want to be sure witch one is in use:

In (at least iPhone 12+) Settings - Cellular - Cellular Data
there is switch "Allow Cellular Data Switching"
with description "Turhing this feature on will allow your phone to use cellular data from both lines ..."